# How to implement Oracle SQL substitution variable for LIKE condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have this query where I need to give input for the name variable similar to the second condition.
How can I do this when I have a LIKE condition?

```
upper(name) LIKE upper('%name%')
 AND trunc(sysdate) - INTERVAL '&NumberDays' DAY ( 3 ) <= create_dt
```

Comment: `upper(name) LIKE upper('%&name%')`?

Comment: Thank you all, such a simple one. I might be blind

Answer (score 3):

Oracle (actually, `sqlplus`) does litteral replacement when it encounters a variable prefixed with an amperstead, so you could simply do:

```
upper(name) LIKE upper('%&name%')
```